# Unable to link native library in MonoTouch project - library not found for -lName

Tags: binding, xamarin.ios, xamarin, native

I've compiled the [flacios library](https://github.com/jhurt/FLACiOS) in xcode. Then I've extracted a "fat binary" from framework folder (build artifact for this particular xcode project) and renamed it to libFLACiOS.a.

Then I've added it to MonoTouch app project. Created a NativeMethods wrapper class where I am importing the native methods I need to use and have added a gcc flags to project Options:

> -cxx -gcc_flags "-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -lc++ -v -Wall -L${ProjectDir} -lFLACiOS -framework AVFoundation -force_load ${ProjectDir}/libFLACiOS.a

Now, it seems like I've done everything required for the import to work, but when I try to build the project I get the following build error:

```
/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch -sdkroot "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer" --cache "/Users/maxpavlov/Perforce/max.pavlov_Moment_5440/Mobile/Sigmo/SigmoIOS/Sigmo/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache" --nomanifest --nosign -dev "/Users/maxpavlov/Perforce/max.pavlov_Moment_5440/Mobile/Sigmo/SigmoIOS/Sigmo/bin/iPhone/Debug/Sigmo.app" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Xml.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Core.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll" -debug -linksdkonly -sdk "7.1" -targetver "7.0" --abi=armv7 "-cxx" --gcc_flags "\"-std=c++11\" \"-stdlib=libc++\" \"-lc++\" \"-v\" \"-Wall\" \"-L/Users/maxpavlov/Perforce/max.pavlov_Moment_5440/Mobile/Sigmo/SigmoIOS/Sigmo\" \"-lFLACiOS\" \"-framework\" \"AVFoundation\" \"-force_load\" \"/Users/maxpavlov/Perforce/max.pavlov_Moment_5440/Mobile/Sigmo/SigmoIOS/Sigmo/libFLACiOS.a\"" "/Users/maxpavlov/Perforce/max.pavlov_Moment_5440/Mobile/Sigmo/SigmoIOS/Sigmo/bin/iPhone/Debug/Sigmo.exe"
Xamarin.iOS 7.2.5 Trial Edition using framework: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk
Process exited with code 1, command:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++  -Wl,-pie  -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk  /Users/maxpavlov/Perforce/max.pavlov_Moment_5440/Mobile/Sigmo/SigmoIOS/Sigmo/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/Sigmo.exe.armv7.o /Users/maxpavlov/Perforce/max.pavlov_Moment_5440/Mobile/Sigmo/SigmoIOS/Sigmo/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/monotouch.dll.armv7.o /Users/maxpavlov/Perforce/max.pavlov_Moment_5440/Mobile/Sigmo/SigmoIOS/Sigmo/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/mscorlib.dll.armv7.o /Users/maxpavlov/Perforce/max.pavlov_Moment_5440/Mobile/Sigmo/SigmoIOS/Sigmo/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/System.dll.armv7.o /Users/maxpavlov/Perforce/max.pavlov_Moment_5440/Mobile/Sigmo/SigmoIOS/Sigmo/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/System.Core.dll.armv7.o /Users/maxpavlov/Perforce/max.pavlov_Moment_5440/Mobile/Sigmo/SigmoIOS/Sigmo/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/registrar.armv7.o /Users/maxpavlov/Perforce/max.pavlov_Moment_5440/Mobile/Sigmo/SigmoIOS/Sigmo/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/main.armv7.o -o /Users/maxpavlov/Perforce/max.pavlov_Moment_5440/Mobile/Sigmo/SigmoIOS/Sigmo/bin/iPhone/Debug/Sigmo.app/Sigmo -framework CFNetwork -framework AVFoundation -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreBluetooth -framework Foundation -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -lz -liconv -u _mono_pmip -u _monotouch_release_managed_ref -u _monotouch_create_managed_ref -u _xamarin_get_block_descriptor -u _monotouch_IntPtr_objc_msgSend_IntPtr -u _monotouch_log /Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.a /Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib/libmonotouch-debug.a "-std=c++11" "-stdlib=libc++" "-lc++" "-v" "-Wall" "-L/Users/maxpavlov/Perforce/max.pavlov_Moment_5440/Mobile/Sigmo/SigmoIOS/Sigmo" "-lFLACiOS" "-framework" "AVFoundation" "-force_load" "/Users/maxpavlov/Perforce/max.pavlov_Moment_5440/Mobile/Sigmo/SigmoIOS/Sigmo/libFLACiOS.a"
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: arm-apple-darwin13.3.0
Thread model: posix
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch armv7 -force_load /Users/maxpavlov/Perforce/max.pavlov_Moment_5440/Mobile/Sigmo/SigmoIOS/Sigmo/libFLACiOS.a -iphoneos_version_min 7.0.0 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk -u _mono_pmip -u _monotouch_release_managed_ref -u _monotouch_create_managed_ref -u _xamarin_get_block_descriptor -u _monotouch_IntPtr_objc_msgSend_IntPtr -u _monotouch_log -o /Users/maxpavlov/Perforce/max.pavlov_Moment_5440/Mobile/Sigmo/SigmoIOS/Sigmo/bin/iPhone/Debug/Sigmo.app/Sigmo -L/Users/maxpavlov/Perforce/max.pavlov_Moment_5440/Mobile/Sigmo/SigmoIOS/Sigmo -pie /Users/maxpavlov/Perforce/max.pavlov_Moment_5440/Mobile/Sigmo/SigmoIOS/Sigmo/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/Sigmo.exe.armv7.o /Users/maxpavlov/Perforce/max.pavlov_Moment_5440/Mobile/Sigmo/SigmoIOS/Sigmo/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/monotouch.dll.armv7.o /Users/maxpavlov/Perforce/max.pavlov_Moment_5440/Mobile/Sigmo/SigmoIOS/Sigmo/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/mscorlib.dll.armv7.o /Users/maxpavlov/Perforce/max.pavlov_Moment_5440/Mobile/Sigmo/SigmoIOS/Sigmo/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/System.dll.armv7.o /Users/maxpavlov/Perforce/max.pavlov_Moment_5440/Mobile/Sigmo/SigmoIOS/Sigmo/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/System.Core.dll.armv7.o /Users/maxpavlov/Perforce/max.pavlov_Moment_5440/Mobile/Sigmo/SigmoIOS/Sigmo/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/registrar.armv7.o /Users/maxpavlov/Perforce/max.pavlov_Moment_5440/Mobile/Sigmo/SigmoIOS/Sigmo/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/main.armv7.o -framework CFNetwork -framework AVFoundation -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreBluetooth -framework Foundation -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -lz -liconv /Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.a /Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib/libmonotouch-debug.a -lc++ -lFLACiOS -framework AVFoundation -lc++ -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.ios.a
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "std::string::c_str() const", referenced from:
      FLAC::Decoder::File::init(std::string const&) in libFLACiOS.a(stream_decoder-823A661D997F1576.o)
      FLAC::Decoder::File::init_ogg(std::string const&) in libFLACiOS.a(stream_decoder-823A661D997F1576.o)
      FLAC::Encoder::File::init(std::string const&) in libFLACiOS.a(stream_encoder-20FCC1D902B5C661.o)
      FLAC::Encoder::File::init_ogg(std::string const&) in libFLACiOS.a(stream_encoder-20FCC1D902B5C661.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

error MT5309: Native linking error: Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
error MT5309: Native linking error: Target: arm-apple-darwin13.3.0
error MT5309: Native linking error: Thread model: posix
error MT5309: Native linking error: "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch armv7 -force_load /Users/maxpavlov/Perforce/max.pavlov_Moment_5440/Mobile/Sigmo/SigmoIOS/Sigmo/libFLACiOS.a -iphoneos_version_min 7.0.0 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk -u _mono_pmip -u _monotouch_release_managed_ref -u _monotouch_create_managed_ref -u _xamarin_get_block_descriptor -u _monotouch_IntPtr_objc_msgSend_IntPtr -u _monotouch_log -o /Users/maxpavlov/Perforce/max.pavlov_Moment_5440/Mobile/Sigmo/SigmoIOS/Sigmo/bin/iPhone/Debug/Sigmo.app/Sigmo -L/Users/maxpavlov/Perforce/max.pavlov_Moment_5440/Mobile/Sigmo/SigmoIOS/Sigmo -pie /Users/maxpavlov/Perforce/max.pavlov_Moment_5440/Mobile/Sigmo/SigmoIOS/Sigmo/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/Sigmo.exe.armv7.o /Users/maxpavlov/Perforce/max.pavlov_Moment_5440/Mobile/Sigmo/SigmoIOS/Sigmo/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/monotouch.dll.armv7.o /Users/maxpavlov/Perforce/max.pavlov_Moment_5440/Mobile/Sigmo/SigmoIOS/Sigmo/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/mscorlib.dll.armv7.o /Users/maxpavlov/Perforce/max.pavlov_Moment_5440/Mobile/Sigmo/SigmoIOS/Sigmo/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/System.dll.armv7.o /Users/maxpavlov/Perforce/max.pavlov_Moment_5440/Mobile/Sigmo/SigmoIOS/Sigmo/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/System.Core.dll.armv7.o /Users/maxpavlov/Perforce/max.pavlov_Moment_5440/Mobile/Sigmo/SigmoIOS/Sigmo/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/registrar.armv7.o /Users/maxpavlov/Perforce/max.pavlov_Moment_5440/Mobile/Sigmo/SigmoIOS/Sigmo/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/main.armv7.o -framework CFNetwork -framework AVFoundation -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreBluetooth -framework Foundation -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -lz -liconv /Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.a /Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib/libmonotouch-debug.a -lc++ -lFLACiOS -framework AVFoundation -lc++ -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.ios.a
error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: std::string::c_str() const. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
error MT5201: Native linking failed. Please review the build log and the user flags provided to gcc: "-std=c++11" "-stdlib=libc++" "-lc++" "-v" "-Wall" "-L/Users/maxpavlov/Perforce/max.pavlov_Moment_5440/Mobile/Sigmo/SigmoIOS/Sigmo" "-lFLACiOS" "-framework" "AVFoundation" "-force_load" "/Users/maxpavlov/Perforce/max.pavlov_Moment_5440/Mobile/Sigmo/SigmoIOS/Sigmo/libFLACiOS.a"
error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're telling the native linker to link `FLAC.a`, because of the `-lFLAC`.

However you said that `FLACiOS.a` exists, which is a different file name. Did you try to change this to match, i.e. `-lFLACiOS` ?

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that -l parameter has to contain the name of the library without .a extension. However, changing the gcc flag to have -lFLACiOS doesn't change anything - I still get the same error message. I've updated the error message to show how it is the same even with -lFLACiOS.

Comment: In fact Xamarin doc basically states that it doesn't matter how you call the -l lib. In their example gcc params are `-gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir} -lMylibrary -force_load ${ProjectDir}/libMyLibrary.a"` and MyLibrary is not libMyLibrary literatly.

Comment: That's not what the doc says ;-) The `lib` prefix is implied but IIRC not required (you might want to rename it to be 100% sure).

Comment: Well, I did and it didn't help. Please the updated error log I've provided in question text, perhaps I renamed something wrong.

Comment: you probably was right about the naming convention. Since now I am getting a different error, and lib not found went away, the initial problem source was naming. Sorry I changed the context of the question now.